# Chart JS title passed from Django - issue with apostrophe &#39

Tags: django, chart.js

I am using chart.js to render data passed from a Django view. I have various types of charts all working well, EXCEPT when my chart title includes as apostrophe.

For example, the title: *My child's learning* gets displayed as: *My child&#39s learning*

The code below shows how I use the title which is the variable chart_row.heading_2 passed from the Django view

```
options: {
    title: {
        display: true,
        text: '{{ chart_row.heading_2 }}'
    }
}
```

The title works in all other instances where there is no apostrophe.

Is there any workaround to this?

Answer (score 1):

OK, I found the answer was to use escapejs:

```
text: '{{ chart_row.heading_2|escapejs }}'
```

From the doc: [Django built-in template tags](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/templates/builtins/#escapejs)

Answer (score 0):

Try rendering the title as safe.

```
options: {
    title: {
        display: true,
        text: '{{ chart_row.heading_2|safe }}'
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks - but the graph just doesn't show when I do that.